# How can I force Ruby to show a full stack trace?

Tags: ruby, stack-trace

I just got this error message:

```
...
from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/...
 ... 10 levels...
from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/...
...
```

and the bug (of course) is hidden somewhere in `... 10 levels...`.

How can I force Ruby to show a full stack trace?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

```
begin
  # Code that raises exception
rescue StandardError => e
  puts e.backtrace
end
```

Comment: How do you show the stacktrace without catching an exception? Just in normal operation, that is.

Comment: @ChiragPatel, maybe you want to use [Kernel#caller](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Kernel.html#method-i-caller).

Comment: Kernel#caller, as Sony Santos mentioned, is absolutely the way to go for what you are wanting. It will return an array of strings. You could easily just do something like the following to get a neat stack trace in your log: Rails.logger.info caller.join("\n")

Comment: By default rescue handles **StandardError** not **Exception**. So you should  rather rescue StandardError. See https://robots.thoughtbot.com/rescue-standarderror-not-exception.